Конфигурация IP TTL в Parallels Desktop для Mac
Есть ли возможность изменить значение TTL для "Shared Network" Parallels Desktop for Mac?
У сейчас меня по умолчанию TTL=128, что не всегда подходит.
Конечно, есть варианты обхода:

Мостовая сеть и настройка TTL в гостевой ОС;
Host-Only сеть и использовать 3proxy или иной прокси.

Но эти варианты требуют индивидуальной настройки каждой ОС, что немного неудобно.
